# Center text inside div

Tags: html, css

How do I target just the text inside the div in order to make the numbers center in the circles? https://jsfiddle.net/Amidi/nevg4gcq/3/

```
<div class="beads">1</div>
<div class="beads">2</div>
<div class="beads">3</div>

.beads{
    background-color: coral;
    border-radius: 100%;
    height: 35px;
    width: 35px;
    text-align: center;
    color: whitesmoke;
    margin-top: 5px;
}
```

Comment: add `line-height: 35px;`. or play with `padding` and remove the `height`.

Comment: Also, post one question at a time. Then make a follow-up question when your first question was answered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Use `display:table` for parent and `display: table-cell` for cell. You must have child element for this approach.

Try this:

```css
.beads {
  background-color: coral;
  border-radius: 100%;
  height: 35px;
  width: 35px;
  text-align: center;
  color: whitesmoke;
  margin-top: 5px;
  display: table;
}
.beads span {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<div class="beads"><span>1</span>
</div>
<div class="beads"><span>2</span>
</div>
<div class="beads"><span>3</span>
</div>
<div class="beads"><span>4</span>
</div>
<div class="beads"><span>5</span>
</div>
<div class="beads"><span>6</span>
</div>
<div class="beads"><span>7</span>
</div>
```

[Fiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/rayon_1990/nevg4gcq/4/)

Answer (score 3):

Just give `line-height: 35px;` to make text center. `line-height` equals to height of the div.

**[Working Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/nevg4gcq/5/)**

Comment: No hard feelings but this this approach will fail if height of the parent changes(something else than _35px_)

Comment: @RayonDabre Yeah check in my answer. It is equals to it's height. If make changes in height then change `line-height` equals

Comment: That is why I mentioned it specifically...;(

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
   .beads{
        background-color: coral;
        border-radius: 100%;
        height: 35px;
        width: 35px;
        text-align: center;
        color: whitesmoke;
        margin-top: 5px;
        line-height: 35px
    }

<div class="beads">1</div>
<div class="beads">2</div>
<div class="beads">3</div>
```